# Snow Leopard Installation says my disk is not GUID

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, partitioning

How can I convert my disk to GUID? When I go to system information, it says the disk is partitioned as APM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Disk Utility (spotlight will find it for you, or if you are booted into the snow leopard disk, it is in the Tools menu of the installer app IIRC), and you will need to go to the `Partition` tab, then `Options...`

[image]

Remember you will lose everything on that drive, **so make sure you have everything backed up first!**

Comment: Options are disabled when the partition is already created. What I did was: get another disk and create a new partition with GUID, then restore the data from the partion in APM. It worked fine this way!

Comment: You can find Disk Utility on the Snow Leopard Installation disk in the "Utilities" menu; or (on an installed system) in /Applications/Utilities

Answer (score 2):

You could boot from you Snow Leopard DVD, create disk image from your current hdisk on a 2nd disk, perform a clean installation of Snow Leopard (this time with GUID partitioning) and then use **Migration Assistant** (`Applications/Utilities`) to migrate the data from the disk image to the new installation.